# Fail to submit a list of object to the model binding using ICollection

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3, model-binding

i have added extra three input fields to my view to enable the system admin to submit four objects at the same time instead of one object at a time; the view looks as the following:-

```
@model Elearning.Models.Answer 
@{ 
    ViewBag.Title = "Create"; 
} 


 <div id = "partialWrapper">
 @using (Ajax.BeginForm("Create", "Answer", new AjaxOptions
{
    HttpMethod = "Post",
    InsertionMode = InsertionMode.InsertAfter,
    UpdateTargetId = "incrementanswer",
    OnSuccess = "removePartial",
    LoadingElementId = "progress2"
}))

 {
     <div id = "returnedquestion">
     @Html.ValidationSummary(true)

    <fieldset> 
        <legend>Answer here</legend> 
        <ol>
      <li>  <div class="editor-label"> 
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Description) 
        </div> 
        <div class="editor-field"> 
        @Html.TextBox("answer[0].Description")
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Description) 
        </div> 
  <div class="editor-label"> 
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.IsRight) 
        </div> 
        <div class="editor-field"> 
             @Html.DropDownList("IsRight", String.Empty) 
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.IsRight) 
        </div>  
        </li>
      <li>   <div class="editor-label"> 
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Description) 
        </div> 
        <div class="editor-field"> 
            @Html.TextBox("answer[1].Description")
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Description) 
        </div>   <div class="editor-label"> 
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.IsRight) 
        </div> 
        <div class="editor-field"> 
             @Html.DropDownList("IsRight", String.Empty) 
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.IsRight) 
        </div>  </li>
       <li>  <div class="editor-label"> 
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Description) 
        </div> 
        <div class="editor-field"> 
            @Html.TextBox("answer[2].Description") 
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Description) 
        </div>  <div class="editor-label"> 
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.IsRight) 
        </div> 
        <div class="editor-field"> 
             @Html.DropDownList("IsRight", String.Empty) 
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.IsRight) 
        </div>  </li>
      <li>   <div class="editor-label"> 
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Description) 
        </div> 
        <div class="editor-field"> 
            @Html.TextBox("answer[3].Description") 
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Description) 
        </div>  <div class="editor-label"> 
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.IsRight) 
        </div> 
        <div class="editor-field"> 
             @Html.DropDownList("IsRight", String.Empty) 
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.IsRight) 
        </div> </li>
        <ol> 
    </fieldset> 
     <input type= "hidden" name = "questionid" value = @ViewBag.questionid>
     <input type= "hidden" name = "assessmentid" value = @ViewBag.assessmentid>
     <input type="submit" value="Add answer" />
 </div>
 }
 </div>
```

and the following Post Ation Method:-

```
[HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Create(int questionid, ICollection<Answer> answer)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {

        foreach (var a in answer){
        repository.AddAnswer(a);

        repository.Save();

        }
        return PartialView("_details2",answer);
    }
    return View("_details2",answer);}
```

and last thing the _details2 partial view which contains the newly added objects:-

```
@model IEnumerable<Elearning.Models.Answer>
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Details";
}


@foreach (var m in Model)
{
        <tr id =  @m.AnswersID>

        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => m.Description)
        </td>
        <td>
            @*@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => Model.Answer_Description.description)*@
            @ViewBag.Answerdesription 
        </td>
        <td>
         @Ajax.ActionLink("Delete", "Delete", "Answer",
        new { id = m.AnswersID },
          new AjaxOptions
          {
              Confirm = "Are You sure You want to delete this Answer ?",
              HttpMethod = "Post",
              UpdateTargetId = @m.AnswersID.ToString(),
              OnSuccess = "removePartial2"
          })


        </td>
        </tr>
}
```

**but the above is not working nethier the objects will be added nor the partial view will be returned , so how i can solve this issue???**
BR

Answer (score 1):

You bind your view to a single `Elearning.Models.Answer` object, how are you expecting to get a collection of Answers as a parameter in your Action? The default model binder will try to bind your view fields to the parameter in the Action but it won't be able to as it's a collection.

What you could try to do is to bind your View to a `List<Elearning.Models.Answer>` and feed it 4 empty Answer objects, then you can create a strongly typed Partial view that expects one `Elearning.Models.Answer`, add the Partial in a foreach and, when posting the form, expect that the default model binder does it work and fill your action method with a brand new List of Answer objects.

As an alternative, you can create a View Model object that contains the fields in your View, including those 4 description fields. You add them as Html.TextboxFor to bind each of them to a different property in the View Model. Then you can collect them in your action, provided you change it to public `ActionResult Create(int questionid, ViewModelAnswer answer)`

Does it make sense?

Answer (score 0):

Your model should contain a list and code like this:

```
@for (int i=0; i < Model.FavouriteMovies.Count; i++) {
   @Html.LabelFor(model => model.YourList[i].Field)
   @Html.EditorFor(model => model.YourList[i].Field)
   @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.YourList[i].Field)
}
```

which will print something like:

```
<label for="YourList_0__Field">Field Name</label>
```

The Field Name field is required.

And receive the model back in your controller:

```
public ActionResult MyAction(MyModel model)
{
     // First element?
     model.YourList[0].
}
```